# Using MySQL on SAN with VPS.net

Tags: mysql

I current run a LAMP server all on one dedicated box.  I am considering moving to VPS.net which is a virtualized VPS system on a SAN.  Does anyone have any experience with a similar setup?  Will being on a SAN hurt or help MySQL performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being on a SAN can be slower than having an HDD all to yourself, depending on how much strain the SAN is put under. You have to keep in mind that a VPS is a shared environment and that you won't have as much performance as you will on dedicated hardware.